# Initialize class in map method

Tags: typescript

I am trying to map a Response array to a Model array.

Response and Model are classes defined in Typescript:

```
class Response {
  userId: number;
  userName: string;
}

class Model {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Then I am trying to map it as follows:

```
models = responses.map((response) => 
  new Model { id: response.userId, name: response.userName }
);
```

It is not compiling and I receive the following error:

```
',' expected
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The class definitions only define the properties, you're not having a constructor. Are you familiar with JS? There are no named parameters.

Comment: Can't a class be initialised in Typescript as it is for example in C#? I was able to do the following in Typescript: let model: Model = { id: 2, name: 'john }; ... So I am not sure why I can't do a class initialisation inside the map function.

Comment: TypeScript has structural typing. If you were to run `model instanceof Model`, it would return false. You still need a constructor in the class definitions, and JS (and therefore TS) requires the constructor to be called. This is assuming you want an actual instance, not just something with the same structure.

Comment: Don't use a class if all you want is to hold those fields, use an interface instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to remember that all of TypeScript's types only exist at compile time, and disappear entirely for runtime.
I'm not familiar with C♯, though from what you're trying to do it seems this isn't the case there.

Without further context on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, there are a couple options available to you.

One option is to have proper classes, as you're likely familiar with in C♯.

```
class Response {
    public userId: number;
    public userName: string;

    constructor(userId: number, userName: string) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}

class Model {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

However, you can take advantage of TypeScript's [shorthand constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#classes),
where you declare the properties inside the constructor.
The following behaves *identically* to the above example.

```
class Response {
    constructor(
        public userId: number,
        public userName: string,
    ) {}
}

class Model {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string,
    ) {}
}
```

With either of these, you'll then need to construct the class when mapping.
JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript) doesn't have named arguments like in C♯ or Python, only positional arguments.

```
models = responses.map((response: Response) =>
    new Model(response.userId, response.userName)
);
```

If you'd prefer having something similar to named arguments,
you can take advantage of [parameter destructuring](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/11/13/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript).

```
// Response omitted for brevity

class Model {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;

    // TS doesn't (yet) have a way to cleanly destructure with type annotations
    constructor({ id, name }: { id: number, id: string}) {
        Object.assign(this, { id, name });
    }
}

models = response.map((response: Response) => new Model(response));
```

The final option is to use an interface,
which *does not* involve the construction of a class,
but rather take's advantage of JavaScript's objects.
To reiterate, these interfaces are *only* at compile time,
and are not enforced at runtime.

This option is most similar to what you already have (and are likely familiar with).

```
interface Response {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
}

interface Model {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Your map will then be similar to what you already had,
just without the class constructor (since no such class actually exists).

```
models = responses.map((response: Response) => 
    ({ id: response.userId, name: response.userName })
);
```

Hopefully these various options give you an idea of what's possible.
If you need more general information,
I highly suggest taking a look at [TypeScript's documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html);
it's fairly easy to read and should be incredibly useful.
If there's something specific to this question,
feel free to leave a comment for clarificaion.

Answer (score 0):

You need the ( )

```
models = responses.map((response) => 
  new Model ({ id: response.userId, name: response.userName })
);
```

Comment: He also needs a constructor that will take the object literal and assign the properties to the class instance..